# Webdav Plugin for Eclipse 3.4?

Tags: eclipse, webdav, ganymede

How do you get webdav support in eclipse 3.4?  The development version of the 3.3 plugin I had been using in 3.3 doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would help if you mentioned what 3.3 plugin you used that stopped working in 3.4. Said that, did you check the [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) project. This is IMHO the most likly place to find WebDAV support.

Comment: You can also check here : http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-team/target.php